# How to save data into CoreData in one view controller, and then have a tableview displaying the data in another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

First and foremost, I am very new to swift programming and I am very unclear about many things and thus I follow guides to make sure my app can work.

Basically, I have been following the guide at (https://www.brianadvent.com/build-simple-core-data-driven-ios-app/) to build a simple core data driven iOS app. I have followed the code exactly and it works. However, I had to make more improvements to the app and that is where the issue happened.

Basically, in the guide, the loading of items into core data and the tableview all exist in the same view controller. In my new app, I would like to have to have the user enter strings which would be stored into core data the same way, and have the tableview display the entered data on another view controller. Quickly I realised that you cannot call variables and functions from different view controllers so I figured creating new variables and moc in the second view controller should not be much of an issue.

This is what I have tried so far. I have kept everything in the code because I fear that is where the error may lay.

The first view controller (where the data is stored into core data:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //name of entity = Alarm
    var alarmItems = [Alarm]() // array of alarm items called     alarmItems
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate


    @IBOutlet weak var engineerName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var dateTimeOfAlarm: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var trueFalseAlarmSelector: UISwitch!

    @IBOutlet weak var engineerComments: UITextField!

    //saving alarm attributes into coredata
    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        engineerName.delegate = (self as UITextFieldDelegate)
        dateTimeOfAlarm.delegate = (self as UITextFieldDelegate)
        //trueFalseAlarmSelector.delegate = self
        moc = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        loadData()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
        engineerName.resignFirstResponder()
        dateTimeOfAlarm.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func dateTimeOfAlarmEdit(_ sender: UITextField) {
        let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action:     #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
        dateTimeOfAlarm.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }

    //sending the attributes to the coredata
    @IBAction func submitAlarmAttributes(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alarmItem = Alarm(context: moc)

        //true/false button checker
        if trueFalseAlarmSelector.isOn {
            alarmItem.trueOrFalseAlarm = true
        } else {
            alarmItem.trueOrFalseAlarm = false
        }

        alarmItem.nameOfEngineer = engineerName.text
        alarmItem.dateTimeOfAlarm = dateTimeOfAlarm.text
        alarmItem.engineerComments = engineerComments.text

        appDelegate?.saveContext()
        loadData()
    }

    //loadData will update the alarmItems array with the new and most current data from the database.
    func loadData(){
        let alarmRequest:NSFetchRequest<Alarm> = Alarm.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateTimeOfAlarm", ascending: false)
        alarmRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        do{try alarmItems=moc.fetch(alarmRequest)

        } catch {
            print("Could not load data")
        }

        //self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

The second viewController (where the tableview resides):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var alarmItems = [Alarm]()
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate


    @IBOutlet weak var historyTable: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var uploadJson: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var refreshTable: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        func refreshButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
            loadData()
        }

        func loadData(){
            let alarmRequest:NSFetchRequest<Alarm> = Alarm.fetchRequest()
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateTimeOfAlarm", ascending: false)
            alarmRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

            do{try alarmItems=moc.fetch(alarmRequest)

            } catch {
                print("Could not load data")
            }
            //self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

        func numberOfSections (in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return alarmItems.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

            let alarmItem = alarmItems[indexPath.row]

            let alarmDate = alarmItem.dateTimeOfAlarm as String?
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = alarmDate

            let alarmEngineerName = alarmItem.nameOfEngineer as String?
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = alarmEngineerName

            let alarmTrueFalse = alarmItem.trueOrFalseAlarm as Bool?
            let alarmTrueFalseString = alarmTrueFalse?.description
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = alarmTrueFalseString

            let alarmEngineerComments = alarmItem.engineerComments as String?
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = alarmEngineerComments
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

The first view controller does not have any error messages whatsoever.

The second view controller however has a lot of issues. For example, at the very beginning, there is this error Type 'SecondViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'". There are a few error messages in some lines that say "Editor placeholder in source file". There is also a "Value of type 'SecondViewController' has no member 'tableView'" error even though I do have a tableView, and lastly,  there is "Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'" at the end.

Thank you so much for helping, I have been trying to figure this problem out for the past few days and I really do not know what else can be done.

Comment: You are writing all you methods inside the viewDidLoad methods. Get your functions out of that methods, and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that what you did was a copy/paste in InterfaceBuilder to create your SecondViewController.

The original code you were using had a variable named `tableView` which is still referenced in InterfaceBuilder.  To fix this, open InterfaceBuilder and find your SecondViewController.  If not already expanded, expand your scene objects and select your SecondViewController then using the Inspector on the right, show the "Connections Inspector".  You will likely find a `tableView` outlet with an exclamation mark and another outlet named `historyTable`.  Simply remove the `tableView` reference and make sure your `historyTable` is propertly linked.

In regards to the "Unresolved identifier cell", its because you misplaced the closing bracket of your `viewDidLoad` function. Since your function is not closed, all other functions thereafter are created as local functions of viewDidLoad instead of functions of your SecondViewController.  To fix your source, simply remove the bracket that is just above `return cell` and add it just `self.historyTable.dataSource = self` (Yes, currently you have it as `self.tableView.dataSource` but your variable is named historyTable).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will try to see if I can fix it now.

Comment: Thank you! I have checked my code according to your comments and I managed to debug it! Now the issue left are layout issues of the app itself, but that is another problem altogether

Comment: Glad it was of help! Don't forget to mark your question as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameREA: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var departmentREA: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var ageREA: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var courseREA: UITextField!

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func saveA(_ sender: Any) {
    let entityA = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Studentsdet" , into: context)
    entityA.setValue(self.nameREA.text,forKey: "name_std")
    entityA.setValue(self.ageREA.text, forKey:  "age_std")
    entityA.setValue(self.departmentREA.text, forKey: "department_std")
    entityA.setValue(self.courseREA.text, forKey: "course_std")
    do{
        try context.save()
        self.nameREA.text = ""
        self.ageREA.text = ""
        self.departmentREA.text = ""
        self.courseREA.text = ""
        
    }catch{
        print("error")
    }
    
}
@IBAction func showA(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let storybd = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let stdA = storybd.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tblVA")as!tableviewAViewController
   
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(stdA, animated: true)
}
```

}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30383553)